# Method of determining dimensions from photographs of multiple angles and degrees of perspective/parallax for a math newbie

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry

I have a project that begins with some 300+ reference photos of a scale model. The only measurements I am certain of are the overall length, and the linear length of one element of one part of the model.

These photographs are in different series, taken with different lenses, at different angles, and none of the metadata is available. They are also of different parts at different angles, which also need to be interpolated and use some sort of mathematics to determine the accurate dimensions of all parts of the model, all the features of the model, and all within a tolerance of 1-3".

So in short, I need the help of someone who can reverse-engineer a photograph in such a way that it accounts for angle of photograph, determines amount of perspective/parallax without knowing what lens or camera was used, what the axis of the object in the photograph is, the distance from the object in the photograph, and with only 2 reference measurements to go from.

I've been fighting with this for weeks... well, rather months, but do not know how to compensate for all of these variables.

I am not very good with math, but if applied to a project, I can often understand it when applied to a project. Anyone who would answer this or wish to help me answer this would need some real patience that I do have a little bit of a learning disability, but this project is important to me. If you have any questions, please contact me.

Comment: I added some tags which seem appropriate, and removed the signature from your post (it's discouraged to sign your posts or add a thank you, since your account is automatically displayed at the bottom of the question anyway).

Comment: Thank you! :) I wasn't sure precisely how to do this, its an odd thing.